# What do you call the building like Sherlock Holmes ( imaginarily ) live?

Tags: word-usage

Could anyone please let me know what you call the building, like the one, which is tall but not wide enough on the street? Can I call it an "apartment"? Or is there better choice to use?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some specific term to describe the particular building that Sherlock Holmes lives in, but in general I would refer to it as either [**a townhouse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Townhouse) or [**a brownstone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownstone). Brownstones are more common in North America though. New York is a place that probably has the biggest number of them. And since, technically speaking, townhouses and brownstones are apartment buildings, you can, of course, call them apartments. But since you're looking for something more specific, *apartment building* would be just too generic a term for your purposes. The following is what the Wikipedia page on brownstones has to say about them:

> Brownstone is a brown Triassic-Jurassic sandstone which was once a popular building material. The term is also used in the United States to refer to a townhouse clad in this material.

This is what a typical brownstone looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the link and the good picture. Though, as you say, **Brownstone** would be more common especially in NY, I am afraid I picked to use townhouse since it is British........but great many thanks.

Comment: @Kentaro Tomono You're right. Stick with **townhouse** as this is probably a more general term for this type of house.

Comment: Sorry, but Sherlock Holmes lives in 221B Baker Street, which is in London, so the correct term is "a tenement" or "a tenement building". No one in the UK would refer to this as a "brownstone".